# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg

Tags: google-chrome, fancybox, mime-types, filepicker.io

I'm using Filepicker.io to handle my image uploads on my website.

I'm also using FancyBox to display a nice slider. Everything works fine if I use a regular image like: `http://i.imgur.com/asdf.jpeg` as the `<img src="">`. Meaning I click the images and the slider pops up correctly.

However when I switch out those static image url's and use my Filepicker addresses, when I click on the images to open the fancybox, the image is downloaded.

Here's the message I get in the console, on Google Chrome:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg: "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/yknn4hWSOOm2NLZYGR3O?dl=false".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems your server sends incorrect http header, please, post it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since your link:

```
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/yknn4hWSOOm2NLZYGR3O?dl=false
```

doesn't have an `image` extension (jpg, png, gif), fancybox doesn't know what `type` of content needs to be handled. You need to tell it by adding the API option `"type": "image"` like:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   "type": "image"
});
```

That is documented here http://fancybox.net/faq, No. 6 (if using v1.3.4), or here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support, FAQ tab, No. 5 (if using v2.x).

For more options how to handle the issue see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17554660/1055987

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it out and share results.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to append the name of the file onto the url, for example:
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/yknn4hWSOOm2NLZYGR3O+photo.png?dl=false

Filepicker.io ignores anything on the file link after the + sign to allow you to make the urls more "adapter friendly"