# Fancybox links don't show in lightbox - what am i missing?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Alright, I thought I implemented this correctly, but I guess I must've goofed somewhere.

Here's my code:

Jquery here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){

$(function() {
    $( ".cta-nav-hover" ).tooltip({
        show: null,
        position: {
            my: "right+40 bottom",
            at: "left bottom"
        },
        open: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.tooltip.animate({ top: ui.tooltip.position().top - 10 }, 75 );
        }
    });
});





$(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});

});
```

Then The HTML:

```
<div id="cta-nav-wrapper">
    <ul id="cta-nav">
        <li class="bio">
            <a href="http://placehold.it/350x125" title="Bio" class="cta-nav-hover fancybox"><span></span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I thought that this would work, but when I click the link, it just brings me to the placeholder image instead of making a popup.  What did I do wrong?  It looks as though i have the files lined up properly, or at least when i inspect them through firebug it goes to the proper js.

Here's what I called in the head:

```
<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/hustle-child/includes/js/fancyapps-fancyBox-v2.1.5-0-ge2248f4/fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/wp-content/themes/hustle-child/includes/js/fancyapps-fancyBox-v2.1.5-0-ge2248f4/fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content/themes/hustle-child/includes/js/fancyapps-fancyBox-v2.1.5-0-ge2248f4/fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/hustle-child/includes/js/fancyapps-fancyBox-v2.1.5-0-ge2248f4/fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/hustle-child/includes/js/fancyapps-fancyBox-v2.1.5-0-ge2248f4/fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/hustle-child/includes/js/fancyapps-fancyBox-v2.1.5-0-ge2248f4/fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/hustle-child/includes/js/fancyapps-fancyBox-v2.1.5-0-ge2248f4/fancyapps-fancyBox-18d1712/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>




<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/hustle-child/includes/js/magnific-popup.css"> 
<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="/wp-content/themes/hustle-child/includes/js/magnific-popup.js"></script>
```

I also tried another plugin called Magnific Popup but it's also unresponsive.  I'm thinking it has something to do with my wordpress theme's set up.

Comment: this `$(function() {` (or `jQuery(function($){` ) is the alias of this `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` so nesting one inside the other is redundant.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This `href="http://placehold.it/350x125"` doesn't say to fancybox that you are opening an `image` so you **either** :

1). add the `fancybox.image` special *class* to your link like

```
<a class="cta-nav-hover fancybox fancybox.image" href="http://placehold.it/350x125" title="Bio"><span></span></a>
```

2). add the (HTML5) `data-fancybox-type` attribute to your link like

```
<a data-fancybox-type="image" href="http://placehold.it/350x125" title="Bio" class="cta-nav-hover fancybox"><span></span></a>
```

3). add the `type` option to your fancybox script like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   type: "image"
});
```

whatever you think works better for your case.

**NOTE**: numbers 1). and 2). above work for fancybox v2.x only. Number 3). works for either v1.3.4 and v2.x

**EDIT** : included a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WWxLQ/)** with your code and jQuery v1.8.3.

There are two links :

- one using "fancybox.image" class : **working**
- other without : **not working**

Comment: Ohhhh Okay that makes sense!  And what if i wanted to display html content in the pop up?  Is there a specified type for that too?

Comment: Hmm, I still can't get it to work with any of those options. i have jquery 1.8.3, is that too old for fancybox?

Comment: @Evan jQuery 1.8.3 is OK, what version of fancybox?

Comment: its 2.1.5  maybe I called it into the head incorrectly, let me edit my question to display what I have called into the head.

Comment: @Evan : here is working with `data-fancybox-type` attribute (requires HTML5 `DOCTYPE`) http://jsfiddle.net/3Nf4c/ and not `fancybox.image` class.

Comment: Alrighty, I'm almost positive that it's something to do with my Wordpress theme that is preventing is from working.  Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @Evan: prob too late, old question, but just in case someone else sees this issue. I spent all day on this and what fixed this for me was removing Google's track outbound links code. It was screwing up the fancybox... I will look into another alt to tracking outbound links with google, but at least I found the issue...