# Fancybox - cannot open image in the Fancybox window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I stuck with setting up the Fancybox window for my photos, I am doing it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

This is initialization of Fancybox. Then the setup of links and images:

```
= link_to i.file_url, :class => 'fancybox', :rel => 'gallery', :title => i.title do
  = image_tag i.file_url, :style => 'width: 150px;'
```

which generates this HTML code:

```
<a href="URL TO FILE" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" title="Item Name">
  <img alt="something" src="URL TO FILE" style="width: 150px;">
</a>
```

But when I click on the link, the image is loaded in the new window instead of in the Fancybox window.
The Fancybox JS+CSS libraries are added correctly - what am I missing yet?

Thanks

Comment: Does your JavaScript console say anything?

Comment: No, the console is empty, no error message.

Comment: Your code is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/vXEqR/

Comment: This is super confusing...

Comment: What kind of URL does `link_to i.file_url` output?

Comment: The URL is like this: `https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/sLTR1nF1QW1234567890`

Comment: Are you sure that the file is valid?

Comment: Yes, I do. When I put it to the URL, I see there the image (I changed the last string as I didn't wanted to put here the original one). But this made me think if cannot be a problem in the format of the URL - if I put the an URL with image extension (like JPG or so), it's working, but not with this URL. Does Fancybox require the file-type extension in the end of an URL?

Comment: Yes, I just tested the ** jsfiddle** by Michael B. and when I put the the generated URL from FilePicker, it doens't work. How to solve this thing?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17554660/1055987 for options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your case is that your URL pattern is not identified by fancyBox.

You should explicitly specify it in your options:

```javascript
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({type:'image'});
```

Comment: Thanks MasterAM. When I try this, I will get this error message (in the Fancybox window): **The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.**

Comment: Which means that the URL is probably invalid.

Comment: No, the URL is valid, I can see the image when I put the URL into the browser.

Comment: I just check the documentation and the correct format is **$(".selector").fancybox({'type' : 'image'});**