# JQuery Fancybox not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I've followed the directions, but Fancybox isn't working right.  I think I need some extra eyes to tell me what I am doing wrong.

Any Ideas?

**HTML**

The code:

```
<h1><a id="v" class= "letter fancybox" data-fancybox-group="group" href="http://placekitten.com/500/500">V</a></h1>
```

The References:

CSS (top of page):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home/css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

JS (bottom of page, including other js):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- FancyBox -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="home/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
```

**JS**

main.js (inside of document ready):

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'fade',
    closeEffect : 'fade'
});
```

I think I should also mention that I didn't put the entire project into one folder.  I put the .css and .js files in separate CSS and JS directories and only included the two referenced files.  I'm wondering if that has anything to do with it and if I should just copy over the source folder and keep everything in there.

Comment: Your script tags are driving me crazy. How do you decide if you want to use the type attribute or not?

Comment: @BillCriswell haha, yeah, I was just thinking about that.  I'd rather just not include them.  Any reason why they need to be there?

Comment: @BillCriswell I just looked it up.  It looks like the type attribute is no longer required in HTML5, but it used to be.

Comment: There's no reason if you're using HTML5.

Comment: Ah, replied at the same time. Yeah, it's not necessary!

Comment: @BillCriswell all type attributes deleted...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox links don't show in lightbox - what am i missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554068/fancybox-links-dont-show-in-lightbox-what-am-i-missing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my own mistake:

My problem was I was referencing a website in my code (even though it creates an image):

```
<h1><a id="v" class= "letter fancybox" data-fancybox-group="group" href="http://placekitten.com/500/500">V</a></h1>
```

It should be something like

```
href="image.png"
```

Comment: @JFK Thanks!  That answer will allow me to include the placekitten link now.  I appreciate the info.

Comment: This worked for me. I was using a bit.ly link for the link instead of a url with a .jpg / .png extension. Small detail but really easy to overlook. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

You should add `type` field in your Fancybox' config. Fancybox tries to detect type of content, but when you `href` to e.g. php script which generates image, Fancybox sometimes can't recognize type of content.

Change:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   openEffect  : 'fade',
   closeEffect : 'fade'
});
```

to:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
   openEffect  : "fade",
   closeEffect : "fade",
   type : "image"
});
```