# Use Data Uri as the href of an a tag

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, href, data-uri

I am creating a single file HTML5 application that has all image resources embedded as a `Data Uri`. This application contains an image gallery (fancy box) that uses `<a>` tags as the source of the image to show in its popup, as many other do. e.g.

```
<li>
  <a href="photos/FL6C2632.jpg">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,somebase64stringetc014564hkjhkj" />
  </a>
</li>
```

Replacing the `src` attribute of the `img` tag with data uri works as expected, however replacing the `a` tag's `href` with a base64 equivalent rather than some genuine path to an image does not.

Is there anyway at all of being able to use data uri in a href attribute rather than an existing physical location?

So for example (which doesn't work)

```
<li>
  <a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,someotherbase64stringetc014564hkjhkj">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,somebase64stringetc014564hkjhkj" />
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: It looks like not all browsers support data URIs for navigation. IE does not, [citing security reasons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897.aspx).

Comment: Additionally to @BoltClock comment, fancybox may not recognize that the (base64) link is an image so you have to specify it. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17554660/1055987 for options

Answer (score 1):

```
<a width="550" height="190" title="" alt="" href=/ onclick="onclick=location.href='data:image/png;base64,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'">Click</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8nxE/1/

Comment: You could have at least used a smaller image that would generate a smaller Base64 footprint.

Comment: Edit for the questioner, the link now actually looks like a link.. had SRC instead of HREF.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/), Fancybox has multiple options. Its default will look for the href parameter of the a tag, but you can always override this. You can for example even load iframes and do ajax requests to fetch more content.

The following is an example using a data url: http://jsfiddle.net/gwwar/qUebx/1/

```
$(".open_fancybox").click(function() {

$.fancybox.open([
    {
        href : 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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',                
        title : '1st title'
    },
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',                
        title : '2nd title'
    },
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg',                
        title : '3rd title'
    }
], {
    padding : 0
});

return false;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is like this:

```
<a rel="group" href='#' onclick="$.fancybox.open({href:'*imageUri*'});">Click here</a>
```

No changes are required to fancybox at all, and you don't need to add any JS methods.