# jQuery: Fancybox plugin redirecting

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using fancybox to show a small QR code, then you can click on the code and it is shown in a lightbox. The problem is, when you click on the thumbnail, you are taken directly to the image instead of it being displayed in the lightbox.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chld=|1&chl=sample_text" rel="fancybox" class="fancybox">
    <img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=50x50&cht=qr&chld=|1&chl=sample_text" alt=""/>
</a>
<script>
$(".fancybox").fancybox( {
    openEffect: 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
});
</script>
```

Here is my code in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zyjfC/1/

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17554660/1055987

Comment: So it is. This solution isn't the most obvious thing in the documentation...

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support FAQ tab, No. 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the link which triggers the fancy box looks for an extension type. (By testing, haven't looked through the source code.)

You can, if you are fine with this, try to fool the script by adding a parameter at the end of you  a href

So your href would look something like this

> http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chld=|1&chl=sample_text**&.jpg**

here is a fiddle with that work around

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zyjfC/2/)

Full code since SO hates jsfiddle links without code

```
<a href="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=500x500&cht=qr&chld=|1&chl=sample_text&.jpg" rel="fancybox" class="fancybox">
    <img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=50x50&cht=qr&chld=|1&chl=sample_text" alt=""/>
</a>

$(".fancybox").fancybox( {
    openEffect: 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',
});
```