# Basic Fancy Box implementation

Tags: fancybox

I am new to html and css. I was trying to create a test Image Gallery to check how fancy box works. I followed all the instructions from youtube and other sites but still I am not able to get the thing to work.
All the required files were loaded.

I apologise for what most may feel is a really simple question. But this is my first attempt so please bear with me.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
 });
</script>



</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">Gallery </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="Images/Gallery/ls/image1"><img src="Images/Gallery/ts/image1"></a></li>
      <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="Images/Gallery/ls/image4"><img src="Images/Gallery/ts/image4"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="Images/Gallery/ls/image6"><img src="Images/Gallery/ts/image6"></a></li>
      <li><a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="Images/Gallery/ls/image8"><img src="Images/Gallery/ts/image8"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">footer text</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put html and css as tags if you want someone to answer

Comment: If your images don't have extension (at least not in your code), then check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support, FAQ tab, No. 5 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/17554660/1055987