# Downloading dynamic image in chrome results in "resource interpreted as document..."

Tags: php, image, google-chrome

There are a bunch of existing questions similar to this one, none of them answer my problem though. It's to do with dynamically generating and downloading images in chrome. Using the example from the php site;

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

```
<?php
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

If I put this into "export.php" and link to it, I get the image as expected. I want this to be a download though, so that the user clicks the link and the image downloads rather than appears in their browser. *Allegedly* the way to do this is with the content-disposition tag, like so;

```
<?php
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

//This is literally the only line I have added
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo.jpg"');    

// Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

And now the image no longer displays (as expected) and all works in all browsers EXCEPT chrome, which now "cancels" the image download when it's done downloading (according to dev tools) - also complains that `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg` in the console.

I have tried every response header under the sun, what am I doing wrong?

response headers:

> ```
>  Cache-Control:max-age=0
>  Connection:Keep-Alive
>  Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="foo.jpg"
>  Content-Length:1302
>  Content-Type:image/jpeg
>  Date:Mon, 14 Oct 2013 09:55:32 GMT
>  Expires:Mon, 14 Oct 2013 09:55:32 GMT
>  Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=43
>  Server:Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
>  X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze15
> ```

**EDIT**

I was trying to simplify the description here but it seems like in simplifying I may have missed out the bit that is causing the issue. The link kicks off some ajax, which generates a POST to the page mentioned above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985003/resource-interpreted-as-document-but-transferred-with-mime-type-image-jpeg)

Comment: Are you sure the file is not downloaded?

Comment: Absolutely positive. It isn't appearing in the downloads window. Been banging my head against the wall about this for around 2 hours!

Comment: This [Issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=163687) describes your _problem_, but there they mention it should be downloaded: (`[...] The canceled request is an artifact of how Chrome and WebKit interact around downloads (the browser process tells WebKit the request was cancelled because it's going to handle it directly rather than handing the data off to WebKit) [...]`)

Comment: have a look at this, maybe it'll help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476362/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-in-php

Comment: I checked your source (did a plain copy and past of your source) and other scripts with `Content-Disposition` all of them show the message and the `cancel` event. But download still works with Chrome (also with your script). I would guess that it's something about your chrome e.g. about it's cache.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies - it looks like this might have something to do with the way the file is being requested rather than the response, I'll update the description.

Comment: @MikeyHogarth How do you create the `POST` ?  With `js` (`XMLHttpRequest`)  or with a form element?

Comment: It's actually the "amcharts" plugin that does it all - it's an old version, I'm looking through the source now to see if I can find how they're doing it (from my perspective, I'm just following their guide and interrogating "$data = &$_POST;").